# Wchan section in ps output not showing anything

Tags: linux, process, kernel, ps

I know that if a process go into `D` state then it means that it is in uninterruptable state. The process can not be killed by any signal. It will only come out of that state on reboot or if I/O wait is over.

I have many process in `D` state which shows that there is something wrong in my machine. Also even after reboot they go back to `D` state. I searched online and find that `wchan` section in ps output tells on what thing in kernel my process is waiting on.

When i use this command `ps axl| grep D` i am getting `-` in wchan column and there is no explanation online what does this means.

This is my sample output for above command.

```
0     0  69970      1  20   0  25064  1088 -      D    ?          0:00 ls -l
```

I am not able to understand what `-` meant in above output.

Answer (score 3):

There are several possibly reasons for wchan being reported as `-` by `ps`:

- the process just isn't blocked in the kernel, i.e. it's running (cf. the ps `state` column)
- the [stack walking procedure](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8.9/source/arch/x86/kernel/process.c#L916) fails due to some corner-case or race condition. It may even fail unconditionally, e.g. on kernels that require proper frame-pointer settings but were compiled without them - check that with `cat /proc/*/wchan` - all 0 output indicates broken wchan support (e.g. currently the case on [Fedora 31 and 32](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1879450))
- you [don't have](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8.9/source/fs/proc/base.c#L391) the necessary [ptrace access mode permissions](https://lwn.net/Articles/692203/) (namely `PTRACE_MODE_READ_FSCREDS`) - unlikely
- the [symbol lookup fails](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8.9/source/fs/proc/base.c#L395) in the kernel - unlikely

Note that recent `ps` version read the wchan information from `/proc/$pid/wchan` which you can access directly by `cat` as well, for easier testing. That file reads `0` if wchan information retrieval failed, which `ps` translates to `-`.

On systems where `wchan` is broken a substitute is to look at (requires root):

```
cat /proc/$pid/stack
```

Or alternatively, consult (doesn't require root privileges):

```
cat /proc/$pid/syscall
```

Answer (score 2):

in the newer linux kernel you see in which kernel function your process is stuck

```
cat /proc/<pid_numer>/stack
```

Comment: No option of `stack`. Kernel version is 3.10

Comment: uname -r                                                                                                             3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64 and you have "cat /proc/self/stack"

Answer (score 1):

Man page for ps has this info, "-" means the process is running.
 WCHAN     name of the kernel function in which the process is sleeping, a "-" if the process is running, or a "*" if the process is multi-threaded and ps is not displaying threads.

Comment: Okey But if `ls -l` is running for so long then their should be someplace it is stuck. How to find that?

Comment: in the linux kernel you see in which kernel function your process stook,cat /proc/<pid_numer>/stack

Comment: you can also use strace -p <pid>  which will detail the system call to debug the problem.